# Password protect Android Studio project

Tags: android, security

I am a full time Android Developer and in the current firm I am working at, I have found my system to have modifications that I didn't perform(when I turned it on the next morning) . I am okay with casual modifications(if at all) but am afraid that if my Android projects may get "stolen", it may get out of hand.

So, without making this a workplace issue, I would simply like to password protect my source.

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Your firm should have told you to `Win+L` lock your computer whenever you leave your seat and change your password at least once a month.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such option in android studio but you can do it so easy. After writing your project you can save it as *password protected Archive file* using [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html)

Go to your project, right click your project folder>>7-Zip>>Add to archive>>Encription>>Add your password>>save. Then delete your project folder after saving and closing android studio.
[Do not use export option in android studio because you will need do download all external libraries next time you open it and there is no password protection]

Comment: Though Win+L can help sometimes.